# MySQL partitioning by customer

Tags: mysql, partitioning, sharding

We have a product that uses diferent MySQL shemas for diferent customers, and a single Java application that uses diferent persistence units for one for every customer. This makes it dificult to add a cutomer withowt redeploying the application.

We are planing to use a single MySQL database schema that hold all the customers with each table having a field which is a KEY sibolizing one customer, so that adding a new customer is a mater od few sql updates/inserts.

What is the best aproach to handle this kind of data in MySQL...does MySQL provide any partitioning tables by key or something like that. And what could be the performance issues of that aproach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few questions here:

Schema Design Question

Partitioning question

Can mySQL handle a HASH MAP Query O(1)

**Schema Design Question:**
Yes, this is much better then launching a new app per customer.

**Can mySQL handle a HASH MAP Query O(1)**
Yes, if the data remains in memory and has enough CPU cycles mySQL can easily do 300K selects a second. Otherwise if the data is I/O bounded and the Disk subsystem is not saturated mySQL can easily do 20-30K Selects per second dependent on the traffic pattern, concurrency, and how many IOPS the database disk subsystem can do.

**Partitioning**
Partitioning means different things in the context of talking about mySQL. Partitioning is a storage engine that sits on top of another storage engine in mySQL to allocate data to a certain table but exposing a group of partition tables as a single table to the calling application. Partitioning could also mean having certain databases execute a subset of all tables. In your context I think you are asking if you federate by customer what are the performance impact. I.e. can you allocate a database per customer if necessary with the same schema. This concept is more along the ideals of Sharding, taking the data as a whole and allocating resources per unit of data e.g. a customer.

**My suggestion to you** 
Make the schema the same per customer. Benchmark all the queries involved that a customer would do. Query patterns that is. Verify that each query with EXPLAIN does not produce a filesort or temporary table, nor scans 100K rows at a time and you should be able to scale no problem. Once you run into issues with a single or set of boxes getting close to you're IOP ceiling think about splitting the data.